# Conditional Function to a pandas dataframe, if vs else change the value

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I been trying to get my code to work but I am having some trouble here.  It would be great if someone could assist me

DF

```
  Col1              Col2          
  2017-01-01        Coffee
  2017-01-01        Muffin
  2017-01-01        Donut
  2017-01-01        Toast
```

How can I change Col2 so that every value that isn't Coffee or Muffin becomes 'Other'?

```
  Col1              Col2          
  2017-01-01        Coffee
  2017-01-01        Muffin
  2017-01-01        Other
  2017-01-01        Other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [265]: df.loc[~df.Col2.isin(['Coffee','Muffin']), 'Col2'] = 'Other'

In [266]: df
Out[266]:
         Col1    Col2
0  2017-01-01  Coffee
1  2017-01-01  Muffin
2  2017-01-01   Other
3  2017-01-01   Other
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU I was wondering how would you change it to not change the missing values.  df.loc[~df.Col2.isin(['Coffee','Muffin', 'nan' ]), 'Col2'] = 'Other' ????